# determine the number of terms in a fibonacci sequence that are divisible by $3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the Fibonacci sequence $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, . . .$ where each term, after the first two, is the sum of the two previous terms. How many of the first $1000$ terms are divisible by 3?

Comment: The fact $(F_a,F_b)=F_{(a,b)}$ (so $F_a\mid F_b$ if $a\mid b$) might be helpful.

Comment: Try dividing the first few by $3$ to see what happens. If you spot a pattern, then prove it persists.

Answer (score 6):

HINT : In mod $3$, 
$$\color{red}{1},1,2,0,2,2,1,0,\color{red}{1},1,2,0,\cdots$$

Comment: The first few are:
1
1
2
3-YES
5
8
13
21-YES
34
55
89
144-YES
233
377
610
987-YES
1597
2584
4181
6765-YES
10946
17711
28657
46368-YES
75025
121393
196418
317811-YES    One out of four, but I don't know how to prove this.